# WebRTC video streaming mute / unmute not streaming after unmute

Tags: javascript, video-streaming, webrtc

I've implemented a video mute and unmute feature that seems to mute the video just fine, but upon unmuting the video, it does not appear to resume streaming the video to the other peer.

To mute, I stop the track as oppose to toggling the `enabled` property, as stopping it turns off the "video on" indicator light:

```js
function muteVideo() {
  localStream.getVideoTracks()[0].stop();
  peerConnection.removeTrack(peerConnection.getSenders()[0]);
}
```

To unmute, I request the camera again (getting a new stream):

```js
async function unmuteVideo() {
  localStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
  document.getElementById('local-video').srcObject = localStream;
  await peerConnection.getSenders()[0].replaceTrack(localStream.getVideoTracks()[0]);
  peerConnection.getSenders()[0].setStreams(localStream);
}
```

And here's a CodePen link to my current WebRTC setup: https://codepen.io/robkom/pen/MWewjLm. I'm testing it in Chrome 85.

My signalling server is a simple websocket server built with `ws` and `@hapi/hapi`. For negotiation, I have the following set up:

```js
peerConnection.addEventListener('negotiationneeded', async () => {
  const offer = await peerConnection.createOffer();
  await peerConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
  webSocketConnection.send(JSON.stringify({ offer: peerConnection.localDescription }));
});
```

When testing, I open the app in one Chrome window, and also the same app in an incognito Chrome window. Everything works as expected and I see video synced between the two windows just fine. When I press mute on one window, it stops the stream and the video element goes black. For the peer in the other window, my video appears frozen. That is also fine. The issue is when I unmute the video, I see my local stream re-appear, but it no longer transmits the new stream to the peer. The peer still sees my frozen face.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using pc.removeTrack which causes a renegotiation that disables the send direction of the transceiver. Replacing the track does not cause a renegotiation so you're not sending.

Either just stop the track (it is mostly ok to have a stopped track on the sender) or change the direction of the associated transceiver again by setting its direction attribute to `sendrecv` again.